# Modify with scapy and netfilterqueue

Tags: python, scapy, netfilter

I'm running Debian with Python 2.7, and scapy/netfilterqueue.

I've added the following in my iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5678 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

And this is my code for getting HTTP packages and changing URL and PORT:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

def modify(packet):
    pkt = IP(packet.get_payload())

    if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.getlayer(TCP).dport == 5678:
        pkt.dst = 'https://my-secure-domain.com'
        pkt.dport = 443

        del pkt[IP].chksum
        del pkt[TCP].chksum
        packet.set_payload(str(pkt))
    packet.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, modify)
try:
    print "[*] waiting for data"
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Running the code does retrieve the correct packages, and it seems the `.dst` and `.dport` is changed, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception socket.gaierror: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known') in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored
```

I'm kinda stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `pkt.dst = 'https://my-secure-domain.com'` to `pkt[IP].dst = 'my-secure-domain.com'` (that's the IP destination, not a URL).

Comment: This gives me `Exception ValueError: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'api'",) in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored`

Comment: I've updated my answer, specify you manipulate the `IP` layer (`pkt[IP].dst` instead of `pkt.dst`)

Comment: Same error: `Exception ValueError: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'api'",) in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored`

Comment: Then that's another error. At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: I’m not getting any line number. The entire error is the one I’ve copy pasted :(

Comment: Ah, I'm setting the url to `my-secure-domain.com/v2/test`, apparently it doesn't like the pat in the url.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, you're setting the IP destination, not the URL. Glad it helped!