# How to sniff pakages and discard?

Tags: scapy

I want to sniff some packets, and if the packet meet some conditions(etc. dst ip = 'xxx') , i want to discard it. Something like firewall.

I am trying use scapy.

`sniff`

I expect I can stop the original packet from src A to scr B if the packet meets the condition

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that using Scapy.
You will need to use:

- On Unix: use netfilterqueue along Scapy, similar to [Modify with scapy and netfilterqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46645142/5459467)
- On Windows: your best bet is `Windivert` (watch out: pydivert doesn't work with the last version. You might want to fix it yourself :/)

In fact, Scapy only receives packets after they went through the OS. It won't be able to discard them. The softwares listed above use tricks to catch them beforehand